# Only the index.php/homepage open while other pages are not opening

Tags: menus, urls

I am developing WordPress theme on local server. Only homepage/index.php is working while other pages in menu are not opening.

I applied the following:

1. change "AllowOverride None to  AllowOverride All"
2. flushing mod_rewrite rules:

   Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save settings
3. Clear browser cache
4. Delete/rewrite .htaccess file

Any other possible solution?

Comment: Have you tried to place the "default" .htaccess to the root of your project?https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp Can you describe us the structure of your files into the local folder? Have you placed wordpress files in the root or in a subfolder?

Comment: i installed WAMP. this is my theme address in localhost C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme